# Summing up values in Pig

Tags: hadoop, group-by, sum, apache-pig

I'm trying to deliver an output which aggregates the last two fields (count and books) and divides them by each other (count/books) for each grouping. Currently I have the grouping code, which groups by the first element in the array. I'm not sure how to get the sums of the last two elements and sum them however. I've posted what code I have so far. Thanks in advance!

```
bigrams = LOAD 'txt' AS (bigram:chararray, year:int, count:int, books:int);
grouping = group bigrams by bigram;

STORE grouping INTO 's3://cse6242vrv3/output1.txt';
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what are you expecting in output. So, I assume you just want to know how to do aggregations in Pig. Let us know more if you are looking for something different.

```
bigrams = LOAD 'txt' AS (bigram:chararray, year:int, count:int, books:int);
grouping = foreach(group bigrams by bigram) generate group AS biagram,
                  SUM(bigrams.count) AS sum_count,
                  SUM(biagram.books) AS sum_books,
                  SUM(bigrams.count)/SUM(biagram.books) AS ratio;
STORE grouping INTO 's3://cse6242vrv3/output1.txt';
```

You can find more details about pig aggregation here-
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/basic.html#group
One more thing you might be interested in pig is nested blocks which can be used for complex calculations in group by.
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/basic.html#nestedblock